# How do I do places API?

Tags: api

I'm trying to learn how to use the google places API.

I try this:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=auck&key=[API-key]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=auck&key=%5BAPI-key%5D)
and when I put it into the address bar I get a response.

But when I try this, for example, I get an error:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=auck&key=[API-key]&type=establishments](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=auck&key=%5BAPI-key%5D&type=establishments)

I've read the documentation for the places API and I don't understand why it's not working...

Is there anywhere I can learn to understand the documentation better?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Is there any more information in the body of the response?  A glance at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types) shows that "establishments" is not a valid `type`, but "establishment" is.  Though only in certain requests.